# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldefault_plugin

Tags: ros

I am making `librviz_tutorial`.

I created a package librviz_tutorial, created all files:

```
/src/main.cpp, /src/myviz.h, /src/myviz.cpp.
```

After catkin_make I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannod find -ldefault_plugin
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is the way you compile everything?

Comment: I use the command "catkin_make" and it gives me an error. So, I cannot even try to open my files before "catkin_make" command works

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, but I actually did not understand how to implement it. I am kind of just learning linux and ros, so I have difficulties. I tried to search for this default_plugin library, but did not find. I did not understand how to define my LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

You must:

- (NOT recommended) either install globally the `default_plugin` library
- (best solution) define your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to allow the system to find the `default_plugin` library, when performing the linking step (which is exactly what `/usr/bin/ld` is trying to do)

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/librviz_tutorial/src/doc/index.rst)?